# Excel INDEX Function: Using a variable range for "Array"

Tags: excel, indexing, range

I am trying to use the INDEX function to search an array for a value. However I would like that array range to be variable. However when I use the Address function to try and specify the range, I get an #value! error. For instance:

`=INDEX($A$1:$B$2,1,2)` Returns the value I want.

`=ADDRESS(1,1,1,TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS(2,2,TRUE)` Returns `$A$1:$B$2`

However `=INDEX(ADDRESS(1,1,1,TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS(2,2,TRUE),1,2)` returns `#VALUE!`

Any help is appreciated. This excel sheet is going to be in the hands of someone else so I'm trying to avoid using macros.

Comment: How is the array determined... if you give more details, we may be able to propose a better solution than using `ADDRESS`.

Comment: I haven't abandoned this thread, I'm just thinking about teylyn's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Address, you can create a range with two Index functions

```
=INDEX($A:$Z,1,1):INDEX($A:$Z,2,2)
```

Wrap an Index around that

```
=index(INDEX($A:$Z,1,1):INDEX($A:$Z,2,2),1,2)
```

[image]

When you step through the formula with the Evaluate formula tool, you can see how the inner Index resolves into the range `$A$1:$B$2`.

[image]